# Sorting an array of JSON objects in ascending order in Laravel Response

Tags: laravel, sorting

I have got a collection of JSON objects whereby am trying to arrange them in **ascending order according to the value in days_left field**. I am using sortBy method but I get this error

> asort() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

I am storing them in a variable called **$life**

Array of JSON objects I am trying to arrange

```
array:62 [▼
  0 => {#375 ▼
    +"customer_id": "2082499"
    +"customer_name": "MARY ***************"
    +"agent_no": "567"
    +"agent_code": "2212"
    +"policy_number": "*************"
    +"plan": "Triplex Term 12"
    +"status": "NOT TAKEN UP"
    +"premium": "10326"
    +"sum_assured": "955000"
    +"effective_date": "2015-04-16 12:00:00"
    +"issue_date": "2015-04-16 12:00:00"
    +"premium_due_date": "2015-04-16 12:00:00"
    +"outstanding_date": "2015-04-16 12:00:00"
    +"maturity_date": "2027-04-15 12:00:00"
    +"days_left": -1341
  }
  1 => {#381 ▼
    +"customer_id": "804286"
    +"customer_name": "PA************** "
    +"agent_no": "567"
    +"agent_code": "2212"
    +"policy_number": "IL201400388092"
    +"plan": "CAREER"
    +"status": "AWA*************"
    +"premium": "3467"
    +"sum_assured": "400000"
    +"effective_date": "2014-03-31 12:00:00"
    +"issue_date": "2014-03-31 12:00:00"
    +"premium_due_date": "2014-03-31 12:00:00"
    +"outstanding_date": "2014-03-31 12:00:00"
    +"maturity_date": "2026-03-30 12:00:00"
    +"days_left": -1722
  }
]
```

Code I am using to arrange in ascending order

```
collect($life)->sortBy('days_left','ASC');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **sortBy()** remove second parameter:

```
collect($life)->sortBy('days_left');
// automatically sorting in ascending order.
```

If you sort in descending order then use:

```
collect($life)->sortByDesc('days_left');
```

I hope it would be helpful.